# Getting error ,not able to send mail using OAuth

Tags: api, linkedin-api, scribe

Hi guys i am getting this error repeatedly . Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error>
<status>403</status>
 <timestamp>1380768861652</timestamp>
<request-id>QDGIGCTHXW</request-id>
<error-code>0</error-code>
<message>Access to posting messages denied.</message>
</error>
```

Although i have sending the proper request but i am not able to sedn the mail.
My code below :
    `String linkedinurl = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox";

         OAuthRequest orequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, linkedinurl);

         OAuthService LINKEDIN_SERVICE = new ServiceBuilder()

         .provider(LinkedInApi.class).apiKey(LINKEDIN_APP_ID)

         .apiSecret(LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET).scope("w_messages").build();`

    
  and also i have set as :
    `orequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml"); and

           orequest.addPayload(xmlBody);

           LINKEDIN_SERVICE.signRequest(accessToken, orequest);`
    
but it is not helping. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi guys i fixed this problem . please follow this http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/3255
my main reason/problem was my xml was not in the below format and scope was not enabled that is "w_message".

```
       <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <mailbox-item>
       <recipients>
     <recipient>
       <person path="/people/id=T4sKMZ8qEN" />
      </recipient>
     </recipients>
       <subject>Invitation to Connect</subject>
     <body>Please join my professional network on LinkedIn.</body>
        <item-content>
       <invitation-request>
  <connect-type>friend</connect-type>
       <authorization>
    <name>NAME_SEARCH</name>
     <value>1Mlb</value>
      </authorization>
        </invitation-request>
      </item-content>
          </mailbox-item>
```